# UIPickerView: Is there a way to stop user from scrolling past a certain row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am looking for a way to stop the `UIPickerView` from scrolling any further down once it hits a certain row. It can still scroll up, but just not down. I would like to perform this when clicked the third row. Here is the code:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [dataArray objectAtIndex: row]);
    selected= row;
    NSLog(@"selected %i",selected);
    self.textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex: row];

    if (row = 3){
         // stop scrolling any lower.
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions. I appreciate any help or tips I get.

Answer (score 1):

Create a property to keep track if the user has selected row 3 (the one with index of 2) Lets call it row3Selected for this example.

```
if (row == 2){
         self.row3Selected = YES;
         [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    }
```

Modify your numberOfRowsInComponent: method to look like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (self.row3Selected) {
        return 3;
    }else{
        return myArray.count // myArray is the array used to populate the picker with data
    }
}
```

This will cause your picker to only display the first 3 objects in your data source.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"You selected this: %@", [dataArray objectAtIndex: row]);
    selected= row;
    NSLog(@"selected %i",selected);
    self.textField.text = [dataArray objectAtIndex: row];

    if (row > 2){
     [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:component animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not stop the user from scrolling down any further -- it will make it jump back to row 2 when the spinning stops.